# sending email using smtp in python not working

Tags: python, email, python-2.6

I am using the below code to send email using python stmp lib. But when I execute the code in unix , it hand ,i.e. the console waits as if it is waiting for me to enter something . I have to do ctrl+Z to exit the program.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
textfile = '/my/folder/file.log'
fp = open(textfile, 'rb')
msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % textfile
msg['From'] = "myid@company.com"
msg['To'] = "myid@company.com"
s = smtplib.SMTP('company.server.name')
s.sendmail("myid@company.com", "myid@company.com", msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Can you please advise where am I going wrong?

Comment: Put `print` statements between some of these lines to figure out where it's getting stuck. Also, please be aware that Ctrl-Z doesn't exit the program, it just suspends it. You might have a few of these processes suspended, which could have consequences depending on what resources they're holding on to.

Comment: Also, if you hit Ctrl-C instead of Ctrl-Z, not only will it exit the program, it will print a traceback showing where Python is stuck. If the top line in the traceback is `s = smtplib.SMTP('company.server.name')`, you know the problem is connecting to or logging into the server. If it's `s.sendmail(blah blah)`, you know it's sending the message. And so on.

Comment: I am getting stuck at `s = smtplib.SMTP('company.server.name')`

Comment: OK, so the problem is that logging into the SMTP server times out. If you `nc company.server.name 25` or `telnet company.server.name 25` from a terminal window, does it immediately come back with a greeting banner?

Comment: when I do a ping to that server  `ping company.server.name` i get  `company.server.name is alive` , so I am assuming it connects from the unix box I am running this.

Comment: That's not what I asked. A machine may be alive, but not listening on the SMTP port. (Also, what Unix are you on where `ping` prints out `company.server.name is alive`?)

Comment: Sorry but when I run that on unix I get `ksh: nc:  not found`

Comment: OK, then use `telnet`. Meanwhile, if you don't know the basics of Unix sysadmin stuff, like how to tell if a server is running, you may get better help at http://superuser.com than here. Anyway, if don't get a banner like "220 server.company.name blah blah ready at blah", that's the problem—there is no SMTP server. If you get a banner, type `HELO my.computer.name` and you should get back a "250 server.company.name blah Hello blah" response.

Comment: Also, the SMTP constructor accepts a `timeout` parameter. You can use this to prevent it from simply locking up. Give it a reasonable amount of time to try, and then handle the exception that should occur in whatever way you like.

Comment: I know this isn't relevant, but I really am curious about your platform. No `nc`, non-standard `ping`, and `ksh` as the default shell… UnixWare/SCO Unix? An actual classic AT&T SVR4 system?

Comment: Thanks got the issue now `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

Comment: OK, so either you have the wrong address, whoever's in charge of that server screwed up, or whoever's in charge of your network connectivity screwed up. No programming problem at all.

Comment: @abarnert answering your other question , I'm not sure , uname gave me the following results though , if it helps `SunOS 5.10 Generic_147440-19 sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200System = SunOS
`

Comment: @misguided: Weird. SunOS 5.10 is the base system for Solaris 2.1, which definitely has `sh` and standard `ping` (although probably not `nc`). Someone's done some funky configuration on it. Oh well, not your problem; thanks for satisfying my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

As @kwatford suggested in comments tried using print statements , found out that the code execution is getting stuck at

`s = smtplib.SMTP('company.server.name')` .

The as @abarnert suggested , tried

`telnet company.server.name`

which failed with the error

`telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

Thus basically the code not being able to connect to the smtp server was causing the issue.